# Streaming tweets with a specific URL in them via anaconda - golang

Tags: go, twitter

I am trying to use the anaconda library in golang to make a tool that allows streaming tweets with a specific URL pattern in them. ex "google.com"

Anaconda : https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda

I quickly noticed that the normal PublicStreamFilter will not work for this use case as the URL in tweets is shortened to a https://t.co domain and hence, adding any kind of URL  to the "track" in the anaconda API will not work as intended.

I looked at the source code for anaconda and there seems to be a SiteStream function as well. my test attempts with it were unsuccessful

```
stream := api.SiteStream(url.Values{
        "track": appConfig.TrackedKeywords,
    })
```

Error message :

```
Twitter streaming: leaving after an irremediable error: 404 Not Found
```

I tried looking for twitter developer docs but could not find anything directly relevant. any advice is appreciated. thanks